# How to locate an element where multiple elements have same id, name and attributes in same tags through Selenium and Java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriver

[image]I want identify second field of first name column.How to identify the second field uniquely.I have tried `//*[@id="depDob($index)"][2]`, but no hope.Here both the first name fields have same attributes which mentioned below.

**Note:** Here that second first name is hidden one.Once we click check box option, we'll get that second firstname field

Can you please some one help on this?

```
<div class="seg2_formBox">
            <label for="depFirstName($index)" class="formly-field-label">First Name *
                <input id="depFirstName($index)" aria-describedby="userDepfn($index)" type="text" maxlength="15" ng-model="user.firstName" class="formly-field-input ng-pristine ng-valid ng-empty ng-valid-maxlength ng-touched" tabindex="0" ng-blur="validateUser(user, 'firstName')" ng-trim="false">
            </label>
            <span class="mbs2_formError" id="userDepfn" aria-live="polite" ng-show="user.firstNameError">Please enter a valid value for First Name</span>
        </div>

<div class="seg2_formBox">
                <label for="depFirstName($index)" class="formly-field-label">First Name *
                    <input id="depFirstName($index)" aria-describedby="userDepfn($index)" type="text" maxlength="15" ng-model="user.firstName" class="formly-field-input ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-empty ng-valid-maxlength" tabindex="0" ng-blur="validateUser(user, 'firstName')" ng-trim="false">
                </label>
                <span class="mbs2_formError ng-hide" id="userDepfn" aria-live="polite" ng-show="user.firstNameError">Please enter a valid value for First Name</span>
            </div>
```

Comment: It looks like the id starts with `depFirstName`. Is this the first or second field html? share the other one as well.

Comment: second field also have same HTML content

Comment: @ManojSoundarrajan I don't see two `First Name *` fields in the _HTML_ you have shared. Am I missing something?

Comment: updated content with more details

Comment: @ManojSoundarrajan Is the _HTML_ of the second **First Name** field which you have published, copied after the _check box option_ have been `clicked`?

Answer (score 2):

To select element by index (in case both input fields are not children of the same parent) instead of

```
//input[@id="depFirstName($index)"][2]
```

try

```
(//input[@id="depFirstName($index)"])[2]
```

Comment: selenium not identifying the element when i use the above xpath.

Comment: Did you try to implement [ExplicitWait](https://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#explicit-waits)?

Comment: I have tried to identify the element using selenium IDE, there itself it's not identifying(highlighting) element.

Comment: Does `<input id="depFirstName($index)" ...>` is correct HTML? Are there two elements with this HTML code?

Answer (score 0):

If you have index changing all the time-

```
//input[contains(@id, 'depFirstName')][2]
```

Comment: selenium not identifying the element when i use the above xpath.

Comment: I have tried to identify the element using selenium IDE, there itself it's not identifying(highlighting) element.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use block class name in xpath and wait until it will be displayed:

```
WebDriverWait inputField = new WebDriverWait(driver, 5);
    inputField.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div [@class='seg2_formBox']//input"))))
            .sendKeys("some_to_input");
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the *HTML* you have shared ofcoarse the the two `<div>` tags with attribute **class="seg2_formBox"** are not identitical. To identify and send a character sequence to the second *First Name* field you can use the following solution:

- Using multiple *class*:

  ```
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='seg2_formBox']//span[@class='mbs2_formError' and not(@class='ng-hide')]//preceding::label[1]")).sendKeys("Manoj Soundarrajan");
  ```
- Using single *class*:

  ```
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='seg2_formBox']//span[@class='mbs2_formError']//preceding::label[1]")).sendKeys("Manoj Soundarrajan");
  ```

Again, the desired element seems to be a [Angular](https://angular.io/) element so you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired *element to be clickable*.

Comment: The above one identifying, first First Name field only.It is not taking second one

Comment: Checkout my updated answer and let me know the result

Comment: How about the second one?

Comment: **//div[@class='seg2_formBox']//span[@class='mbs2_formError']//preceding::label[1]** I have tried this xpath, but ide not finding